# have to save UITextfield's value to the NSUserDefault

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am a new comer to the iPhone world, I am having a question,I am having a login page in  which 2 levels and associated 2  uitextfield,i have to save both the UITextfield's Values(inputt by user) to the NSUserDefault,and new time when we start application both the UITextfield should be filled with the values we hav input before....i am in bid trouble

code would be appreciated

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)saveLoginToUserDefaults:(NSString*)loginString
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:loginString forKey:@"Login"];
    }
}

-(NSString*)retrieveLoginFromUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *val = nil;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Login"];

    return val;
}
```